# svn permission problems chmod

Tags: debian, svn

I am having problems commiting files to an svn repository via tortoise svn.

On a commit, I get the error:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Can't chmod '/mnt/svn_repos/software/db/transactions/3719-1.txn/rev': Operation   
Error: not permitted  
Finished!:
```

From reading other articles I figured it was because the user running `apache` ( in my case www-data ) wasn't the owner of the repositories.

So, logged in as root, I did this:
chown -R www-data:www-data software

But ls -al reveals that root is still the owner of that folder and I still get that error on a commit.

I did `chmod -R 777 *` on the entire repository.

Any ideas?

NB. I have been able to commit to this filesystem in the past. We had to reboot our machine and apache did not start automatically, so we had to start it manually ( just via /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start ) and since doing that I am no longer able to commit.

Comment: I see that the path is `/mnt/svn_repos/` which makes me think that it isn't on the root filesystem. What filesystem is svn_repos on? Is it on a FAT/NTFS, is it network mounted via samba? Is it on another filesystem that doesn't support *nix user/permissions? Your SVN repository, should almost certainly be hosted on a local filesystem.

Comment: How does the client authenticate? Over SSH?

Answer (score 0):

If you use NTFS/FAT. Find www-data UID(33 in my Ubuntu):

```
$ LC_ALL=C id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

and mount partition with ouid=33 option.